# Adding data from one list to another with correct ID of list item SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

We are trying to get around the limitation of Field Permissions in SharePoint by creating a second list which will allow users to edit what they are allowed, instead of the whole form. In this case, it is on field that is set to Person or Group (Dashboard). For reference, the Person or Group gets info from AD, I am not sure if that is standard or not info but thought to add it in.

We have created a second list that has two fields, one being a Person or Group (AddToDashC) and the second being plain text (CopyName), where a workflow triggers and sends the Person or Group to plain text as Display Name, as that is what shows in the Person or Group. Last Name, First Name. This workflow works fine.

On the main list, we have separate list items where the Dashboard field can be edited, being unique for each list item. I can’t figure out the logic to be able to match the IDs up so that we can transfer the CopyName information to populate the correct list item ID through a workflow. We have a Lookup on the first list (AddtoDashWFC) which grabs the plain text form, CopyName, but just trying to figure out how to populate it properly.

I was hoping to have an edit link next to each list item in the column, which will go to the second list but still link to the report through the ID.

Sorry for the seemingly basic question, I just can't get the logic.

[List 2 Workflow so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGuTM.png)

[List 1 Workflow so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoimM.png)

Thanks,

Patrick